# ASM parameter numbering

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm, bytecode-manipulation, jvm-bytecode

Let's say I have a dummy class

```
public class B {
    public Object run(long v, String f){
        if(v == 2) {
            if(f.equals("x")) {
                return new Object();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

asmifier will create the following for the `run` method:

```
{
mv = cw.visitMethod(ACC_PUBLIC, "run", "(JLjava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;", null, null);
mv.visitCode();
mv.visitVarInsn(LLOAD, 1);
mv.visitLdcInsn(new Long(2L));
mv.visitInsn(LCMP);
Label l0 = new Label();
mv.visitJumpInsn(IFNE, l0);
mv.visitVarInsn(ALOAD, 3);
mv.visitLdcInsn("x");
mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/lang/String", "equals", "(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z", false);
mv.visitJumpInsn(IFEQ, l0);
mv.visitTypeInsn(NEW, "java/lang/Object");
mv.visitInsn(DUP);
mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESPECIAL, "java/lang/Object", "<init>", "()V", false);
mv.visitInsn(ARETURN);
mv.visitLabel(l0);
mv.visitFrame(Opcodes.F_SAME, 0, null, 0, null);
mv.visitInsn(ACONST_NULL);
mv.visitInsn(ARETURN);
mv.visitMaxs(4, 4);
mv.visitEnd();
}
```

And I don't get this bit:

```
mv.visitVarInsn(ALOAD, 3);
```

The way I see it, there are only three arguments for `run`:

```
0: `this`
1: v:J
2: f:Ljava/lang/String
```

So why is `f` now loaded using `3` rather than `2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the [Java Virtual Machine Specification chapter 2.6.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.6.1) says

> A value of type long or type double occupies two consecutive local
>   variables.

and

> The Java Virtual Machine uses local variables to pass parameters on method invocation.

Therefore the arguments for your example are:

```
0: `this`
1: v:J
3: f:Ljava/lang/String
```